# Librosa generated waveplots are flat for certain audio sounds

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, audio-processing, librosa

Certain wave plots generated by librosa’s display module are just flat lines that fill the entire axes.

I used native sampling rates to load some wav files into librosa and my dataset is a mix of stereo and mono files. I know the wave plots are incorrect because it looks nothing like the frequency-time plot of the same files in audacity.

I've tried playing with the figure width, height and DPI, however there are no improvements in the generated waveplots. Below is the waveplot generated by Librosa for one of these audio files and the expected wave plot in audacity.

[Librosa Waveplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8f4xe.png)

[Audacity Waveplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1gxl.png)

The code used to generate the plot is derived from the librosa documentation:

```
    sound, sr = librosa.load(input_dir, sr=None)
    matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
    librosa.display.waveplot(numpy.array(sound), sr=sr)
    matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout()
```